# Manipulate conversations in microsoft teams channels

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-teams

I need to write a plugin for `Microsoft Teams` so if this plugin installed on user client or the entire team space, The members conversations in channels automatically manipulated when the user scrolling in channels.
I read through [Microsoft Teams developer documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/mstdd-landing) especially the [Designing your Microsoft Teams app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/design/design-teams-app-overview) section and looked into its [Samples](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-ui-templates/ts) but I didn't find out how to do that. The SDKs and the Development Kits there only allow to work within an App not the entire client. I appreciate for any help in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: If you want to get Chat/channel conversation,you can use the graph Api-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get-conversation?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Teams SDK's and Development kits allows developers to develop the applications that will integrate inside Teams client but can not directly use to develop the apps on top of Teams Client itself.

We won't allow 3rd party developers to directly work with Teams Client product itself.

M365 plugins link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/m365-plugins/m365-plugins-overview

However you can subscribe to channel to get notifications:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http